# When plotting Mandelbrot using NumPy & Pillow, program outputs apparent noise

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, complex-numbers, mandelbug

Previously, I had created a Mandelbrot generator in python using turtle. Now, I am re-writing the program to use the Python Imaging Library in order to increase speed and reduce limits on size of images.

However, the program below only outputs RGB nonsense, almost noise. I think it is something to do with a difference in the way NumPy and PIL deal with arrays, since saying `l[x,y] = [1,1,1]` where `l = np.zeros((height,width,3))` **doesn't** just make 1 pixel white when `img = Image.fromarray(l)` and `img.show()` are performed.

```
def imagebrot(mina=-1.25, maxa=1.25, minb=-1.25, maxb=1.25, width=100, height=100, maxit=300, inf=2):
    l,b = np.zeros((height,width,3), dtype=np.float64), minb

    for y in range(0, height):
        a = mina
        for x in range(0, width):

            ab = mandel(a, b, maxit, inf)

            if ab[0] == maxit:
                l[x,y:] = [1,1,1]

            #if ab[0] < maxit:
                #smoothit = mandelc(ab[0], ab[1], ab[2])
                #l[x, y] = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(smoothit, 1, 1)

            a += abs(mina-maxa)/width
        b += abs(minb-maxb)/height

    img = Image.fromarray(l, "RGB")
    img.show()

def mandel(re, im, maxit, inf):
    z = complex(re, im)
    c,it = z,0

    for i in range(0, maxit):
        if abs(z) > inf:
            break
        z,it = z*z+c,it+1
    return it,z,inf

def mandelc(it,z,inf):
    return (it+1-log(log(abs(z)))/log(2))
```

UPDATE 1:

I realised that one of the major errors in this program (I'm sure there are many) is the fact that I was using the x,y coords as the complex coefficients! So, 0 to 100 instead of -1.25 to 1.25! I have changed this so that the code now uses variables a,b to describe them, incremented in a manner I've stolen from some of my code in the turtle version. The code above has been updated accordingly. Since the Smooth Colouring Algorithm code is currently commented out for debugging, the `inf` variable has been reduced to `2` in size.

UPDATE 2:

I have edited the numpy index with help from a great user. The program now outputs this when set to 200 by 200:

[image: Failed Mandelbrot]

As you can see, it definitely shows some mathematical shape and yet is filled with all these strange red, green and blue pixels! Why could these be here? My program can only set RGB values to `[1,1,1]` or leave it as a default `[0,0,0]`. It can't be `[1,0,0]` or anything like that - this must be a serious flaw...

UPDATE 3:

I think there is an error with NumPy and PIL's integration. If I make `l = np.zeros((100, 100, 3))` and then state `l[0,0,:] = 1` and finally `img = Image.fromarray(l)` & `img.show()`, this is what we get:

[image: Not just 1 white pixel!]

Here we get a series of coloured pixels. **This** calls for another question.

UPDATE 4:

I have no idea what was happening previously, but it seems with a `np.uint8` array, `Image.fromarray()` uses colour values from 0-255. With this piece of wisdom, I move one step closer to understanding this Mandelbug!

Now, I **do** get something vaguely mathematical, however it still outputs strange things.

[image: Black circle in White Background.]

This dot is all there is... I get even stranger things if I change to `np.uint16`, I presume due to the different byte-shape and encoding scheme.

Comment: It is usual to escape the Mandelbrot iteration when the magnitude of the complex value exceeds `2` not `10**100`.

Comment: Yes, I see why that might seem extraordinarily strange. It is because I'm using the Smooth Coloring Algorithm to, well, colour each pixel. It requires a very large "horizon", on the order of 10**100.

Comment: Interesting. I cannot provide a citation for "when the magnitude reaches 2 the function value will eventually escape" (perhaps in "The Science of Fractal Images" co-author B.B.Mandelbrot). But the thing is, at the lower iteration areas (where the function escapes) the contours are smooth, so iterating further is time waste. It is only near the boundary of the M-Set (near maximum iterations) where my image rendering looks chaotic. Does having a high escape value improve that? I have not worked on Mset for a number of years so can't immediately test that.

Comment: Well, the idea of the Smooth Colouring Algorithm is to gain a floating point pseudo-number-of-iterations before the orbit escapes. In order to make the differences noticeable, the numbers have to be big (since we are using logs, which although are continuous they will from a practical perspective reduce the "colour spanning" or differences between pixels). You can find more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Continuous_.28smooth.29_coloring

Answer (score 4):

You are indexing the 3D array l incorrectly, try

```
l[x,y,:] = [1,1,1]
```

instead. For more details on how to access and modify numpy arrays have a look at [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

As a side note: the [quickstart documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) of numpy actually has an implementation of the mandelbrot set generation and plotting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This seems to have brought me a step closer!

However, the program still isn't correct - I will look at the link you have given me and although it uses matplotlib, I'm sure it will be helpful. Anyway, I have fixed other things and will update the post shortly explaining the fixes.

Comment: The matplotlib function[plt.imshow()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) does pretty much the same as the PIL .show() method:
If the given array is 3 dimensional and the last dimension is of size 3 (like your l array) it will interpret it and show it as RGB image

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, but to add to your update saying that you don't have to assign l[x,y,:] an array: that is true, this is a feature of numpy called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), with a special case being the assignment of a scalar like l[x,y,:] = 10 (this will set  l[x,y,0] == l[x,y,1] == l[x,y,2] == 10)

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks, this is true!